# InjectionException - Eclipse 2018-12 e4 export

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

When running my RCP application in Eclipse it works correctly. If I export using the `Eclipse Product export wizard` and execute the application I get InjectionExceptions.

I've found another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52207542/rcp-application-run-from-eclipse-runs-fine-exporting-it-throws-injectionexcepti) that is the exact same problem. I've added `org.apache.felix.scr` to the product configuration but I'm still getting the same issue. I'm assuming another plug-in needs to be added but `Add Recommended` doesn't add any more.

**Start Levels**

[image: Start Levels]

**Exception example**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-03-05 09:35:24.650
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon' from bundle '64'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-03-05 09:35:24.650
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.ContextProcessingAddon' from bundle '64'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "ContextProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: What do you have configured for the Start Levels?

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm using the default values when adding them using `Add Recommended`.

Comment: Start levels look OK. For e4 you need everything listed in the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature (and the two EMF features it depends on).

Comment: Do you mean I need to add them to the Start Levels or elsewhere?

Comment: The start levels are OK. I am talking about the plugins required.

Comment: It is far easier to use a feature based build, since you only have to list a small number of features rather than a long list of plugins. [This tutotial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html) covers features

Comment: Okay I've managed to change over to using features instead of plugins and the application executes. When exporting I get an error. `..\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\compile.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.xml:6: The following error occurred while executing this line:`. My `feature.xml` is copied straight from that tutorial you linked. I've just changed the names around.

Comment: Do you have any ideas for what might cause this? I've been looking this up for the last few hours and the only things I can find that are similar have been fixed by installing/updating pde.

Comment: What 'following error'? Doesn't it provide more details? I've no idea what that message is about.

Comment: There isn't anything else. It doesn't give any information about the error  apart from the line number in the xmls. Below this is the same but instead of the `feature.xml` it  is about the `build.xml`. The errors extend so far that the dialog box can't display them all. I can take a screenshot tomorrow to show you.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more of the messages.

Comment: Found it in the logs. `build.xml:43: The following error occurred while executing this line:` is repeated for multiple lines. A `StackOverflowError` occurs. `java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:571)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)`. It might be best for me to create a separate question to give more detail.

Comment: I've created a new question with more detail on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021437/eclipse-e4-export-build-xml-a-problem-occurred-while-executing-this-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by finding the required plug-ins for the feature that @greg-449 mentioned.

First I added `org.eclipse.emf.common` and `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` to the `Plug-ins and Fragments` of the product file.

Next I right clicked and opened each of them to look at their dependencies. I then stepped through each dependency and if I didn't have it in my Required Plug-ins (`plugin.xml`) I would add it.

Comment: For everyone new to the Eclipse RCP business: Don't confuse the "Start Levels" for the "Debug Configuration" and the "Start Levels" in the "Configuration Tab" for the .product config file. This misunderstanding costs me hours. ;)