# Eclipse e4 export - build.xml: A problem occurred while executing this line:

Tags: java, ant, eclipse-rcp, e4

I've recently changed my Eclipse e4 applications project configuration from being based on plug-ins to features. The application runs correctly but when exporting I get errors to do with a `build.xml` file.

**Error**
[image: Problem Occurred error]

**.metadata/.log - Shortened**

```
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\compile.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.xml:6: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:43: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:24: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:43: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:24: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:43: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:24: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:43: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:24: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\my.name\Workspace\project_name\build.xml:43: The following error occurred while executing this line:
...

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:571)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:535)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.runScript(FeatureExportOperation.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.ProductExportOperation.run(ProductExportOperation.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

After searching around I've found a couple of similar questions to do with this. To fix it people were installing/updating PDE. I've tried reinstalling it but it hasn't made a difference. Also I'm quite sure it is installed correctly as when the project configuration was based on plug-ins it would get the whole way through the build process.

**feature.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="[![enter image description here][2]][2]feature.name"
      label="Feature"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
   </license>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid" version="1.0.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.formattedtext" version="1.0.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.core.di" version="1.7.100" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.osgi.services" version="3.7.100" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt" version="0.14.400" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench" version="2.1.200" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.apache.commons.io" version="2.2.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.apache.commons.lang3" version="3.1.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.slf4j.api" version="1.7.2" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="MyPlugin1" version="1.0.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="MyPlugin2" version="1.0.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jface" version="3.15.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="javax.annotation"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.swt"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.swt" version="3.104.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.commands" version="3.4.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="3.3.0" match="compatible"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher" version="1.5.200" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.junit.platform.launcher"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher" version="1.0.0"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="feature.name"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.apache.commons.io"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.apache.commons.lang3"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.slf4j.api"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.jface"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="MyPlugin2"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"/>

   <plugin
         id="MyPlugin1"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"/>

</feature>
```

**Product File features**

[image: Problem Occurred error]

What could be causing this?

Comment: Looks like some sort of recursion in the PDE generated build.xml causing the stack to overflow. What is in your feature.xml and the xxx.product file?

Comment: @Greg I've added information for the `features.xml` and product file features. Is there any other information that would be useful?

Comment: Build problems are extremely difficult to debug remotely. `feature.name` in your plug-in list doesn't look right. It is simpler to use features in the 'requires' list rather than specific plugins.

Comment: That is a good point. `feature.name` is not a plug-in so it shouldn't be there and could mean things are stuck in an infinite loop? The problem is that if I don't have it there it says `The following problems were detected: feature.name is missing`. when I run the application.

Comment: I've found this that looks similar although they've produced it with different steps. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335670     

I've not got `Generate metadata repository` selected as that option doesn't exist though.

Comment: The option is called 'Generate p2 repository' these days.

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be. I've tried switching all the options around to no avail. 

You mentioned above about a `requires` list. Where is this?    
I've found `Required Features/Plug-ins` but if I try adding `feature.name` it can't find it. I can add my other features successfully though.

Comment: The <requires> xml tag is called Dependencies in the feature.xml editor

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to put the product file to another plug-in product.