# Eclipse 2022-03 RCP App can be debugged but the exported app fails to start

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I can debug and run my Eclipse RCP application with Eclipse 2022-03 without any problems. After exporting the app the start fails with the following logs created:

```
!SESSION 2022-03-20 22:04:19.506 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.2
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState -data @user.home/temp/workspace

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2022-03-20 22:04:33.177
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon' from bundle '415'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at de.filocut.filocam.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2022-03-20 22:04:33.181
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.ContextProcessingAddon' from bundle '415'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "ContextProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at de.filocut.filocam.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2022-03-20 22:04:33.199
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.cleanupaddon.CleanupAddon' from bundle '416'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CleanupAddon.eventBroker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at de.filocut.filocam.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2022-03-20 22:04:33.208
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon' from bundle '416'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "MinMaxAddon.eventBroker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at de.filocut.filocam.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-03-20 22:04:37.463
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at de.filocut.filocam.rcp.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopException(ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2834)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:637)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at de.filocut.filocam.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.core.runtime.dynamichelpers.IExtensionTracker.registerHandler(org.eclipse.core.runtime.dynamichelpers.IExtensionChangeHandler, org.eclipse.core.runtime.dynamichelpers.IFilter)" because the return value of "org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench.getExtensionTracker()" is null
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchServiceRegistry.<init>(WorkbenchServiceRegistry.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchServiceRegistry.getRegistry(WorkbenchServiceRegistry.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ServiceLocator.getService(ServiceLocator.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.getService(Workbench.java:3350)
    at de.filocut.filocam.common.GlobalModel.<init>(GlobalModel.java:277)
    at de.filocut.filocam.common.GlobalModel.<clinit>(GlobalModel.java:87)
    ... 20 more
```

I found other messages with the same/nearly the same error like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000091/injectionexception-eclipse-2018-12-e4-export). But the solutions did not work for me.

Any hint is appreciated. Am I missing some plugin, configuration, ...?

Comment: This sort of error is extremely difficult to diagnose in a SO question. Possibly most likely missing start levels or missing plugins. Use "Add Required" in the .product file Content tab to see if it adds anything. Use "Add Recommended" in the "Start Levels" section on the Configuration tab. I strongly recommend using Feature based products with your own feature plus standard Eclipse features which gives you a known good set of plugins.

Comment: I know this is a difficult sort of problem. All the more it is super awesome that you fixed the problem. :) The "Start Levels" were completely missing. I only added them in the "Debug Configuration", but missed the part for the product export. Many thanks. I am new to the topic and have inherited an eclipse product. ;) And can you recommend a "Plugin to Feature" migration tutorial? Maybe this is a good topic for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the comment from @greg-449 I found the solution very fast. You need to check your "Start Levels" on the "Configuration Tab".

[image]

I only checked the "Start Levels" in the "Debug Configuration", and not for the product export.